# File.Readdir() can't be called more than once?

Tags: go

When i study Golang, I write the code bellow:

```
list1,_ := f.Readdir(-1)
len(list1) //some value

list2,_ := f.Readdir(-1)
len(list2) //0
```

When os.File's method Readdir() called more than once, it will always return an empty []FileInfo.

I want to know why?  And how to make my code work?

Comment: "Subsequent calls on the same file will yield further FileInfos. [...] If n <= 0, Readdir returns all the FileInfo from the directory in a single slice." https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Readdir Why would you call Readdir multiple times with -1? Just re-use the slice returned by the first call.

Answer (score 2):

According to Golang spec for [Readdir](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Readdir):

> If n > 0, Readdir returns at most n FileInfo structures. In this case,
>   if Readdir returns an empty slice, it will return a non-nil error
>   explaining why. At the end of a directory, the error is io.EOF.

It is returning empty because you have reached the file end `EOF`. If you want to read the same file again. You should move the pointer to the start of the file to read it again.

```
list1,_ := f.Readdir(-1)
len(list1) //some value

if _, err := f.Seek(0, 0); err != nil { // seek to the start of the file
    panic(err)
}

list2,_ := f.Readdir(-1)
len(list2) // will not return 0
```

Seeking the file pointer is easy:

```
func (f *File) Seek(offset int64, whence int) (ret int64, err error)
```

> Seek sets the offset for the next Read or Write on file to offset,
>   interpreted according to whence: 0 means relative to the origin of the
>   file, 1 means relative to the current offset, and 2 means relative to
>   the end. It returns the new offset and an error, if any.

Comment: @robx it is an exmaple let me set it to `0` offset to seek the pointer to the start of the file.

Comment: Set a good example by providing readable code. Write `io.SeekStart`, not `0`, for the `whence` value: https://play.golang.org/p/hzk8sKsJriV